# how to create install data file in magento 2?

Tags: database, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

in magento 1 
code is

```
INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('table_name')} (`color_id`, `color_name`, `color_code`) VALUES
(1, 'Green', '#A2C44C'),
(2, 'White', '#FFFFFF'),
(3, 'Blue Dusk', '#304050 '),
(4, 'Black', '#28272c'),
(5, 'Azalea', '#e975a4'),
(6, 'Cardinal Red', '#891c2f'),
(7, 'Carolina Blue', '#6e95ce'),
(8, 'Cherry Red', '#b3042b'),
(9, 'Chestnut', '#7d5b52'),
(10, 'Daisy', '#fed348'),
(11, 'Dark Chocolate', '#3c3230'),
(12, 'Forest', '#333a32'),
(13, 'Gold', '#feac1c'),
(14, 'Heliconia', '#d1316f'),
(15, 'Honey', '#edb963'),
(16, 'Ice Grey', '#c2bebf'),
(17, 'Indigo Blue', '#4a5d7b'),
(18, 'Iris', '#497bba'),
```

how i set this code in the magento2 in installData.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module folder, create a **Setup** folder and **InstallData.php** file

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /**
         * Prepare database for install
         */
        $setup->startSetup();

        $columns = [];
        $columns = ['color_id', 'color_name', 'color_code'];
        $data = [];
        $data[] = ['1', 'Green', '#A2C44C'];

        $setup->getConnection()
                ->insertArray($setup->getTable('your_table_name'), $columns, $data);

        /**
         * Prepare database after install
         */
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

*PS: prior to this you need a **InstallSchema.php** in order to create your custom table*

Comment: @Rahulocodewire you welcome!

Comment: can you tell me please how i insert one or more colors in this table  when i upgrade get error my code is this $data[] =[('1', 'Green', '#A2C44C'),
['2', 'White', '#FFFFFF']; how i update two or more colors

Comment: Try this: `$data =[['1', 'Green', '#A2C44C'], ['2', 'White', '#FFFFFF']];`

Comment: this is not work